# from 1 point in a numpy array to another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coordinates, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have this numpy array:

```
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

And I want to print the coordinates going from the first 1 to the second 1.

this is my code:

```
 def walking(start, end):
     for j in range(end[0]):
         start[0] += 1
         print(start)
     for k in range(end[1]):
         start[1] += 1
         print(end)
```

But I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this

As an example:

above you can see the numpy array. the first '1' is located with coordinations:

```
[0,1]
```

and the second 1 is located with the coordinations:

```
[2,1]
```

so to get from the first '1' to the second '1' I would have to go throuh the coordinations:

```
[0,1], [1,1], [2,1].
```

And that is what I want to be printed (or returned)

So for another example:

```
[[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

above you can see the numpy array. the first '1' is located with coordinations:

```
[0,2]
```

and the second 1 is located with the coordinations:

```
[4,4]
```

so to get from the first '1' to the second '1' I would have to go throuh the coordinations:

```
[0,2], [1,2], [2,2], [3,2], [4,2], [4,3], [4,4]
```

And that is what I want to be printed (or returned)

Comment: What would be the expected output? How do you define the path? How should it generalize?

Comment: I think you should clarify what you means by start and end in your function. Adding a reproducible example would be key for help

Comment: @Zelemist I edited it with an example. So with start and end I mean the coordinates of the '1''s. In doesn't matter at which '1' you start, as long as you go from the one to the other.

Comment: @mozway generalizing it, so it's better suited for a np array? since I don't think this works well in a np array. What do you mean with how do I define the path?

Comment: I meant, shortest path? angle? diagonal? Here it seems quite straightforward

Comment: @mozway From what I understand it's x first than y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do it:

## Header:

```py
import numpy as np # Import

# Creating an array for the example
arr = np.array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.,], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,], [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.,], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,]])
x,y = np.where(arr == 1.) # Select the 1.

print(f"First 1. : ({x[0]}, {y[0]})") # Print the coordinates of the first point
print(f"Second 1. : ({x[1]}, {y[1]})") # Print the coordinates of the second point

first = [x[0], y[0]] # Creating a list of the coordinates
second = [x[1], y[1]] # Creating a list of the coordinates
```

## Code:

```py
# The function
def walking(start, end): 

    """ Print a path from start to end """

    print(start, end=", ") # Print the first term 
    while start[0] != end[0]: # While start.x != end.x
        start[0] += 1 if start[0] < end[0] else -1 
        print(start, end=", ") # Print start with a separation with ", "
    while start[1] != end[1]: # While start.y != end.y
        start[1] += 1 if start[1] < end[1] else -1
        print(start, end=", ") # Print start with a separation with ", "
```

Concerning the `1 if start[n] < end[n] else -1`:
Its to handle the case where it can be an array that looks like that:

```py
[[ 0. 1.]
 [ 1. 0.]]
```

## Executing the code:

```py
walking(first, second) # Prints: [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4],
```